# Can't bind to 'data' since it isn't a known property of 'teach-data'

Tags: angular

Why do I get the following error:
`Can't bind to 'data' since it isn't a known property of 'teach-data'.`

When trying to:

```
<teach-data *ngIf="selectedData" [data]="selectedData"></teach-data>
```

TeachDataComponent

```
..some imports
export class TeachDataComponent implements OnInit {

    public requests;
    @Input() data;

    constructor(private http: Http, private JwtService:JwtService,
    private _service: NotificationsService) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {

    }
```

*worked in RC.4

*Hapenned after trying to upgrade to Angular 2 RC.5

Comment: Please post your definition of teach-data directive.

Comment: `<teach-data></teach-attacks>` ?

Comment: @lexith sry I just tried to simpllify my code in here, edited

Comment: @Lucio Posted in question

Comment: To avoid confusion with HTML native attributes use two words, also modify the declaration on the component as follow: `@Input('my-data') myData: any;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you've followed all the [steps for migrating to RC 5](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/rc4-to-rc5.html). In particular, [step 2: Create an NgModule](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/rc4-to-rc5.html#!#2-create-an-_ngmodule_). Try importing the `teach-data` component and adding it to the "declarations" section of the `@NgModule` statement.

Answer (score 0):

I've got same error message when I was trying to pass a complex type from parent component to child component in angular 11.2.11

I had to add the type of 'data':

```
@Input() data: any;
```